# Java find and compare members by string (maybe JPA feature?)

Tags: java, database, jpa, reflection, dictionary

I've got alot of beans with attributes, which are derived from database tables with JPA. The users shall be able to enter any column name and a value as a string, and the app shall automatically find the correct member in the one of the beans.

I must use JPA, otherwise I would use some JDBC meta data to put all columns and values into a normal map. Is something like this possible with JPA? It only has to work from database to beans, I don't want to persist changes.

If this doesn't work, can I somehow analyze member names programmatically at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EntityManagerFactory has a [getMetamodel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html#getMetamodel%28%29) method, which returns its MetaModel. From this MetaModel, you may ask for the MetaModel of every entity class, and discover all its attributes, their types, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In case the JPA part doesn't work, you can access class members (fields, methods) of your class as follows:

```
Field[] fs = YouClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

Details for accessing different members are on [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html)